# Flip over with blanks java

Tags: java

I want to take a string then flip over the string if they are same print `"same"` if not print `"not same"`. These codes okey for me but if i take a string with blanks like `"r a d a r"` the program asking `"continue?"` but it didn't wait my answer.. directly quit..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sormak {

        public static void main(String[]args) {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);;
            String yes = "yes";
            String cont = ""; 

            do {
                String reserve = "";
                String input1 = "";

                System.out.print("give me string");
                input1 = input.next();

                for(int i=input1.length(); i>0; i--)
                {
                    reserve = reserve + input1.substring(i-1,i);
                }
                if(input1.equalsIgnoreCase(reserve))
                    System.out.println("same!!");
                else
                    System.out.println("not same");

                System.out.print("continue?");
                cont = input.next();

            } while (cont.equalsIgnoreCase(yes) == true);

        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the javadoc of Scanner.next() say? When you browse the methods offered by Scanner in the javadoc, can't you find one which would return a whole line?

Comment: give me string radar
same!!
continue?yes
give me stringr a d a r
same!!
**continue?furkan@fujitsu:~/Desktop$**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, you need to read the whole line to get the answer.

```
System.out.print("continue?");
while (!cont.equals("\n")) {
   cont = input.next();
   answer += cont;
}
} while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(yes));
```

Comment: yeah thats good, ı wrote"yes" but it didn't return the "give me string"